# How to change the keyboard layout in Google Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

Right now the keyboard layout does not work with a Danish keyboard layout, all special characters do not show like `|`.

How do I change the keyboard layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try manually changing the alt-gr setting in the [Cloud Shell Keyboard Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDgVp.png)? This should give you access to the special characters.

Comment: That worked, I did see the option but I did not understand at all what it meant, even though I am used to configuring my keyboard layout because I used a Danish layout. Thank you a lot! 