# Wrong keyboard on Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm really stuck with this, Google Cloud Shell Terminal does not recognize my keyboard well (all other tools, from Google or not, don't have this problem).
It's OK for all letters but other characters are wrong.
I have a laptop with AZERTY keyboard, and when I type:

- & => it writes 1
- 1 (shift + 1) => it writes !
- , => it writes , (oh, this one works!)

I have tried to play with the keyboard settings but nothing seems to work...

Do you know what's happening ?

Thank you

[edit]
I've tried the different options below, nothing seems to work. If I open Cloud Shell Editor instead of Cloud Shell Terminal, it works well. Only the terminal does not recognize my keyboard...

[image: Cloud Shell Keyboard Options]

Comment: From your description and reading here ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY  It sounds like Cloud Shell is simply seeing your keyboard as a US keyboard?

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55161468/how-to-change-the-keyboard-layout-in-google-cloud-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you may be affected by this issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1245196

Deleting the .config/google-chrome folder seems to fix the issue, although only temporarily.

Edit: The issue is fixed as of Chrome 95

Comment: it looks like a bit of this, but I'm only affected when using Google Cloud Shell Terminal (all other tools are OK). I've tried to go in incognito mode and it doesn't work either. Haven't tried yet to delete the chrome folder. EDIT - ok this comment is completely my case https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1245196#c16

Comment: I have verified this issue is fixed in Chrome 95 (promoted to stable yesterday)

Comment: I confirm, updating Chrome has solved the issue !

Answer (score 3):

To adjust your terminal settings, click the Cloud Shell Settings button. You can set your Terminal preferences for the keyboard.

Also, check **Terminal Preferences → Keyboard → Alt Gr Key**. There is a setting to automatically detect the keyboard from the browser's language setting.

Comment: This is my current setting (https://imgur.com/a/S2vgPUj). I've tried all combinations, it didn't change at all. Should I restart Cloud shell everytime I change ?

Comment: @ValentinCoudert - edit your question can copy/paste the image. Do not use an external link. At this point, I don't know. If you can translate French to English, I might be able to review the screenshot.